# Setting up android studio with external libraries

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, junit4, android-uiautomator

Trying to create a android junit ui test. 
I've installed on my mac android studio, from project structure added Library Dependency of junit4, then added Module Dependency of android and uiautomator.
Gradle took care of setting up dependencies.

I went ahead to ApplicationTest class, and added import clauses for junit ui automation:

```
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiScrollable;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiSelector;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;
```

but I get an error `Cannot resolve symbol 'UiObject'`. It can't find these packages

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add exact error to your question?

Comment: Getting `Cannot resolve symbol 'UiObject'` and so on for all imports

Comment: Could you see if Gradle has succeeded download the library?

Comment: @Lompa, I'm seeing a folder 'uiautomator' on the project folder that contains uiautomator.jar and build.gradle - so I assume gradle was successful adding the libs

Comment: @azv Try File > Invalidate cache / restart

Comment: @Lompa- thanks! This solved the issue. I'm not really sure if I like or hate gradle :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue.

Firstly, please make sure you are using new call tree

`import android.support.test.uiautomator.UiObject`

If you still face this issue, then try:

`File > Invalidate cache / restart` should resolve this issue